# How to create this bootstrap carousel of iframes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can I use Bootstrap to create a carousel of video's (iframe's) with the layout as below?

[image: desired carousel]

The code that I'm currently using is below. The problem is that:

- the carousel indicators are displayed on top of the video (makes them hard to see) instead of below it.
- the carousel automatically goes to the next video after a few seconds. Instead I would like the carousel to only go to the next video if the visitor clicks on the carousel indicator.

  ```
  <div id="carouselvideo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xxx?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xxx?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xxx?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you are asking. Simply move this:

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
```

Out of the `<div id="carouselvideo">` container. As long as the `data-target` points to `#carouselvideo`, the `ol` can be anywhere on your page.

For the JS, you would set the option for `interval` to `false`

`$("#carouselvideo").carousel({interval: false});`

Comment: Thanks it worked with one exception. Placing the indicators code outside the carousel, seems to be causing some problems: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34122874

Comment: Ah, yeah. I forgot you needed that bit of js when the controls are outside. It looks like you have it figured out, though.