# Bootstrap carousel: carousel-indicators not changing size/class

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted the carousel-indicators below the images. This required some styling changes to still use Bootstrap for this carousel (see full code below). I added the `border-color` to the indicators and I added a bit of styling to the `carousel-indicators` class: `position:static; padding-top:10px; width: 100%; margin-left:0;`.

The problem is the size of the indicators. If a visitor clicks one of the indicators, the carousel correctly goes to that image. **However, the indicators don't change: that is, the indicator that started as `active` is still larger than the other two indicators** (you would now expect the clicked indicator to be the larger one). The first indicator continues to keep the `active` `class`. What could be causing this problem?

```
<div id="carouselvideo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xxx></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xxx></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <iframe width="250" height="250" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xxx></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>       //The problem persists also if I remove this script line.
  $("#carouselvideo").carousel({interval: false});
</script>

<ol class="carousel-indicators" style="position:static; padding-top:10px; width: 100%; margin-left:0;">
  <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="0" style="border-color: #333;" class="active"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="1" style="border-color: #333;"></li>
  <li data-target="#carouselvideo" data-slide-to="2" style="border-color: #333;"></li>
</ol>
```

---

**Update:** If I move the last five lines inside the `carouselvideo` div, then the problem is gone. However, I dont wan't it there because I want the indicators below the carousel (see [How to create this bootstrap carousel of iframes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34121547)). Why would this problem exist when the indicators code is placed outside the carousel?

Comment: Could you please reproduce your problem in a snippet/fiddle, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example of a bootstrap carousel and the indicators work just fine.  You are missing some quotes at the end of your iframe src and this may be causing some issues but you can find a working example at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/auotu240/ and here is the code

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

        <div class="item active">
          <iframe width="100%" height="250" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xxx"></iframe>

        </div><!-- End Item -->

         <div class="item">
         <iframe width="100%" height="250" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xxx"></iframe>

        </div><!-- End Item -->

        <div class="item">
          <iframe width="100%" height="250" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/xxx"></iframe>

        </div><!-- End Item -->
      </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
      <!-- Controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      </a>
    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
```

you can take out the script and just put data-interval="false" in your carousel as well but it is up to you if you are still having issues then there is some more than likely some previously stated css or javascript issues.  You may take out the controls if you dont want them and just keep the indicators.

I found that if you want the indicators outside of the carousel the active class no longer toggles so you would need to add the following script

```
<script>
$(".carousel-indicators li").on('click', function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the missing quotes and placed `data-interval="false"` inside the carousel. Unfortunately, the same problem persists. In comparison to the working example (which I indeed used as basis for my code), I moved the indicators outside the carousel (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34121898).

Comment: It works when I place the indicators code at the bottom inside the carousel div, thanks

Comment: I have added some code to the answer in case you want to keep the controls outside of the carousel as they will not toggle the active class outside of the carousel

Comment: I see you updated your question so you will need to add the code that I have added to my answer to change the active class bootstraps javascript has everything tied into the #Carousel div.  You can either use the code I added or you can use position absolute for your indicators and use bottom:-20px or something to get the indicators below the iframe